# How to I stop duplication on SQL join where I have order_ids and when people order more than 1 item (so multiple product_ids) to calculate discounts?

Tags: sql, dataset

So my problem is my discount number is blowing up because an order has a discount for the entire order, but I am making a dataset where there are multiple lines for each order to represent each product in the order. Instead of the discount only applying once to the order, it adds the discount for every line.

what is happening

| order_id | product_id | quantity | amount | discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | b | 1 | 10 | 7 |
| 3 | a | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | b | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | c | 1 | 15 | 5 |

what i want

| order_id | product_id | quantity | amount | discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | b | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | a | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | b | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | c | 1 | 15 | 0 |

I just want the discount to be applied once per order, and my join is using order_id so that is why the discount is applying multiple times. I would attach my code, but it's a decent sized CTE

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: @NickW updated to what I think you mean

Comment: This site is great - https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables . Just jot up your data in Excel or freehand enter then it spits out table that stack overflow (and most things that use markdown ) will display as a nice table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I did need to use a row_number() Over Partition by Order id, but I was also losing records if the order had more than 1 item. The solution was to use a CASE WHEN statement.

```
CASE WHEN ORDER_ROW_COUNT = 1 THEN DISCOUNT ELSE 0 END
```

this allowed me to keep the records without duplicating the discounts

Answer (score 0):

You’re joining on a field that isn’t unique so the join is returning all the records for that order Id and therefore the discount is being applied to all the records for that order Id. You need some sort of differentiator field. Something that is unique in each orders data set.

Example:

```
Select *, row_number () over(partition by order_id order by order_id) as rownumber into #temp from table
```

This should give you something like in the picture.
[rownumber table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERWnS.jpg)

Then join on order_Id = order_Id and rownumber =1 and this would only update the first record for each order.